# Анимация не дает label перемещаться WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Есть label, который можно перемещать мышью. Есть анимация Label, которая срабатывает при MouseEnter. Суть анимации в том что она перемещает Label по Canvas.Top - тоесть с начальной позиции(981) она передвигает label на Canvas.Top(810). После этого при попытке переместить мышью label не получается(выше 810 не поднимается, а по x двигается хорошо)
Вот код анимации

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.To = 810;
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
label.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, animation);
```

Код перемещения label:

```
private Point? _movePoint;
//Событие которое происходит при нажатии на кнопку мыши
        private void Btn_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lb = sender as Label;
            _movePoint = e.GetPosition(lb);
            lb.CaptureMouse();

        }

        //Событие которое происходит при отпускании кнопки мыши
        private void Btn_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lb = sender as Label;
            _movePoint = null;
            lb.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        //Событие которое происходит при перемещении мыши
        private void Btn_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lb = sender as Label;
            if (_movePoint == null)
                return;
            var p = e.GetPosition(this) - (Vector)_movePoint.Value;
            Canvas.SetLeft(lb, p.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(lb, p.Y);
        }
```

Comment: а как именно вы перемещаете мышью label?

Comment: сделал правку в вопросе

Comment: А можно ещё код, которым вы вызываете вашу анимацию? Ну то есть XAML, судя по всему.

Comment: Анимацию я вызываю в C# коде, label.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, animation);(в вопросе я показывал, как я ее создаю при событии MouseEnter)

Comment: как я понял, после окончания анимации объект не сохраняет изменения в canvas.top, поэтому ее надо убирать по окончанию и присваивать canvas.settop(координата по окончании анимации)

Comment: Дело в том, что анимация «сильнее», чем непосредственное присвоение значения. Я попробую написать, как это обойти, когда доберусь до компа.

Comment: @VladD В общем чтобы label двигался по заверению анимации мы, когда она заканчивается обрабатываем событие `animation_left.Completed += new EventHandler(compl);` а далее: `private void compl(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(card_completed, StartPosLeft);
            card_completed.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, null);}`
Однако это неудобно, что скажите?